# R sweave writes connection closed warning message on PDF output

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

I am producing iteratively thousands of PDF reports based on a `.Rnw` template. The charts I include are pre-generated as `.png`, not generated on the fly.

My issue is that about 1% of the times (I haven´t found a pattern so far), I get a very visible pink warning message:

> ## Warning: cerrando la conenexion 3 (report.Rnw) que no esta siendo utilizada

The R code I use to generate the PDF from Sweave is:

```
Sweave2knitr(file = "report.Rnw",
             output = "./temp/report-knitr.Rnw")
knit2pdf(input = "./temp/report-knitr.Rnw",
         quiet = TRUE,
         clean = TRUE,
         envir = environment(),
         encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Additionally, I use the library kableExtra to generate tables and xelatex.

Apparently, regenerating the file makes the message go away, so I use the package pdftools to open each report and check for error messages, but I am still concerned and curious about why I get the message, for I don't open explicitly any connection in my scripts, so a part of R/LaTeX compiler must be doing it.

How can I control that my scripts don't leave any connections open?

Comment: Since it is listing "report.Rnw" as the connection name, it looks as though the problem comes from the Sweave2knitr() call.  But why would you want that?  Why not use Sweave() if it is Sweave source, or convert the original once, not thousands of times?

Comment: @ user2554330 It's been some time since I included that line, and I'm quite new to LaTeX and Sweave so I cannot argue why in this case I have to first use Sweave2knitr. According to its documentation, it makes the .Rnw knitr-compatible. I have some LaTeX code inserted dynamically in the PDF, plus if I run **knit2pdf(input = "./report.Rnw")** it just won't generate the report.

Comment: The error message I get is a little cryptic, but it says: **Quitting from lines 52-55 (./report.Rnw) 
object 'tex' not found
Warning message:
In remind_sweave(if (in.file) input, sweave_lines) :
  It seems you are using the Sweave-specific syntax in line(s) 39, 51, 60, 69, 112, 149, 157, 167, 175, 185, 198, 209, 217, 227, 236, 246, 256, 266, 295, 305, 333, 347, 373, 416, 445, 465, 490, 509, 533, 552, 577, 589, 599, 624, 634, 648, 658, 677, 689, 703, 715, 725; you may need Sweave2knitr("./report.Rnw") to convert it to knitr**

Comment: You should look at the input and output files from Sweave2knitr, and just generate things like the output file in the first place.  Generally the changes Sweave2knitr makes are pretty small and easy to avoid in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in `Sweave2knitr()`.  It opens a connection to the source file and never closes it.  The connection will be closed at the next garbage collection, which can happen at fairly unpredictable times.

So to fix this, don't call `Sweave2knitr()` so many times (as I suggested in my comment), or call `gc()` afterwards to generate the warning before calling `knit2pdf()`.  That might slow things down, but probably not noticeably, since `knit2pdf` is likely pretty slow.

Comment: Thanks! I just merged your PR https://github.com/yihui/knitr/pull/1432, which means this issue has been fixed in the development version of knitr.